# Need docker host ip in order to resolve url to my microservice

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have 2 microservices 1) shortUrl service 2) redirection service.
ShortUrl service converts a longurl to short url like : http://redirection-service-ip:redirection-service-port/hash-for-long-url and stores (hash-for-long-url, longurl) to db.

Now a user can just paste the generated shorturl to browser which is actually the call to redirection microservice with path param as hash-for-long-url. Redirection service simply fetches the long url from db using hash and redirects (302) the request to original long url of the user.

This setup works perfectly fine on localhost. I am fetching the ip address to generate short url using `InetAddress.getLocalHost().hostAddress` function in java. But this doesn't work when i deploy everything to docker because using above function docker can simply provide container ip address which is not accessible from browser. Even when I try to access swagger-ui for docker deployed services , I need to use docker host ip address (with respective ports of each service).

I want to know if there is any solution so that I can pass docker host ip to my microservice which will make the generated short url to be accessed from browser just like swagger ui. Or is there a way that I can expose container ip address so that it can be accessed via browser.

Comment: In the general case that's something you need to configure externally.  Is your machine running behind a load balancer, or a firewall service, such that external clients need to connect to something else that forwards requests on to you?  You can't tell that from just the local system, whether in a container or not.

Comment: @DavidMaze I understand what you mean. Currently what I expect is to run docker containers on my local host and resolve the url from browser of my machine , something similar to what I am currently doing to access swagger-ui using docker host ip.

Comment: Are you using docker on windows/macOS?
In this case you cannot access the docker IPs directly. 

For windows/macOS the only option is a port-forward. (`-p 8080:80`) https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/

Comment: hey @SimGel , I am already exposing the ports in docker compose using below config 
` shorturl:
    build: ./shorturl
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"`
Is this what you mean or do you suggest something else.

Comment: Okay. I assume you are exposing both services then? Shorturl on 8080 and Redirection on 8081 or someting like this? In this case the Shorturl service must generate the URL with localhost:8081.
But as @DavidMaze already stated you should set this externaly.
The containers can talk to each other with their internal IPs. But since you accessing the service via localhost the internal IPs are useless.

Comment: If you are using a port-forward your machine is creating a DNAT which forwards the traffic from localhost:8080->container:8080. But the container is not aware of the DNAT.

Comment: @SimGel spot on. You are right. The thing is though , I am able to access swagger ui of both the services with docker-host-ip eg: http://192.168.99.100/swagger-ui/index.html , so is there a way that I can pass/access docker host ip which is 192.168.99.100 to my microservice ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @DavidMaze stated you should pass the external part of the URL to the container.

One option is using environment variables.

- Via Docker run: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/
- Docker compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

So in your case you have to pass an environment variable to the shorturl-service containing the host/port of the redirection service.

example:

```bash
docker run -it --env REDIRECTION_SVC=http://localhost:8081 debian
```

Inside your container you can read the value from the environment of the process.

in bash this would be:

```bash
echo $REDIRECTION_SVC
```

**Update:** read from java:

```java
System.getenv("REDIRECTION_SVC");
```